# Getting invalid_client with OAuth2 Drive API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I've created a project in Google Cloud Console, and I'm pretty sure my AppEngine project is associated with it (clicking on the AppEngine link in the project shows an overview of my AppEngine project).

I've uploaded my project to run on appspot.com.

I've properly copied and pasted the console project's OAuth2 client secret and id to be used by the Python library.

I've properly setup the consent screen.

I've added the callback urls.

I've made sure that the appropriate API's are turned "ON" and green (Google Drive).

But I'm still getting `Error: invalid_client` when trying to authenticate.

What did I miss?

**EDIT**: Here's the url where it goes wrong

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-app-id.appspot.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fview%2F0Ao7HHtqOGzZ7dDNneTg0b1R0bnVJNzRvWk9DVVhIVXc%3A9wi8bS1R7fejjVuDd9IdPjoxMzg0NjgyNDU5&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-app-id.appspot.com%2Foauth2callback&response_type=code&client_id=abcxyz123.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.readonly&access_type=offline
```

and the following text (with an image of a broken robot):

```
Request Details
  cookie_policy_enforce=false
  response_type=code
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
  redirect_uri=https://my-app-id.appspot.com/oauth2callback
  access_type=offline
  state=https://my-app-id.appspot.com/spreadsheet/view/0Ao7HHtqOGzZ7dDNneTg0b1R0bnVJNzRvWk9DVVhIVXc:9wi8bS1R7fejjVuDd9IdPjoxMzg0NjgyNDU5
  client_id=abcxyz123.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Drive API? The link to do this is more obvious if you use the old form of the API Console (see the faint grey link at the bottom of the new API Console page).

Otherwise, if you did what you said you did, you haven't missed anything.

For any Oauth problems such as this, it is immensely helpful to paste the http request and response into your question. This page tells you how to do that https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

A really good debugging technique is to put your code to one side and use the Oauth2 Playground (with your own application credentials configured). You can compare the http traffic from the Oauth playground with the traffic from your app, and play spot-the-difference.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the Drive API is enabled. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: I've never coded oauth from Android, so these comments may be incorrect... (1) your state looks quite odd. Did you set that, and if so what happens of you omit it. (2) I'm not sure if access_type=offline works on Android. Can you try to auth using Oauth Playground and spot the difference?

Comment: Ah this is an AppEngine app. The state is a url of my app. Tried spot the difference with oauth playground, and it seems the only difference is that there's no `state` param in the playground, and the `approval_prompt` param is missing on mine.

Comment: And I tried adding the `approval_prompt=force` param to my url, but it's still giving `invalid client`)

Comment: Ignore my "Android" comment. That's what happens when I answer two questions at once :-)

Comment: When you used the Oauth playground, did you enter your own Client ID (under the Gear/Use My Credentials setting), or default to the playground-app? If the latter, try the former.

Comment: Just tried using my own credentials for the playground, got the same `invalid client` error. Thanks, didn't know about this playground. This will come handy in the future.

Comment: Cool. so you've eliminated your code and narrowed it down to how the app was registered in the API COnsole.